# couchbase help does not work

Tags: couchbase

I just downloaded Couchbase for OS X (community edition) and started it up.  That part went well.  Then I started up the command line shell, cbq, and tried to run commands according to their docs:

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html#topic_bzd_zwr_w5

I can successfully run things like:

```
select * from `beer-sample` limit 1;
```

...but I cannot run the metacommands like:

```
\HELP;
\ECHO hello;
```

Those all come back with an error response:

```
cbq> \HELP;
{
    "requestID": "a52b8f2f-bef3-4d6f-83a8-f839ad1a87bb",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 3000,
            "msg": "Input was not a statement."
        }
    ],
    "status": "fatal",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "401.285µs",
        "executionTime": "347.522µs",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0,
        "errorCount": 1
    }
}
```

and

```
cbq> \ECHO hello;
{
    "requestID": "0ec331ca-9f74-409f-b904-6d9543af73da",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 3000,
            "msg": "syntax error - at hello"
        }
    ],
    "status": "fatal",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "492.399µs",
        "executionTime": "431.839µs",
        "resultCount": 0,
        "resultSize": 0,
        "errorCount": 1
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should work, which version of the community edition are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me...

```
cbq> \help;

Help information for all shell commands.

\ALIAS [ name value ]

\CONNECT url

\COPYRIGHT

\DISCONNECT

\ECHO args ...

\HELP [ args ... ]

\POP [ parameter ]

\PUSH [ parameter value ]

\QUIT 
\EXIT

\REDIRECT OFF | filename 

\SET [ parameter value ]

\SOURCE filename

\UNALIAS name ...

\UNSET parameter

\VERSION
```